# empty form received by the controller

Tags: vb.net, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I don't know what I've done wrong, or what could have caused this bug. When I submit this form to the controller, the controller receives 2 empty fields:

Here is the form inside the view:

```
@Using Html.BeginForm("contactSearch", "search", FormMethod.Post)
    @Html.TextBox("SearchString")
    @Html.DropDownList("opportunite", "Choisissez une opportunité")
    @<input type="submit" value="Submit!" />
End Using
```

And here is the controller:

```
    <HttpPost()>
    Function contactSearch(ByVal search As String, ByVal opportunite As opportunite) As ViewResult
        If opportunite Is Nothing Then
            ModelState.AddModelError("opportunite", "Opportunite is empty")
            ViewBag.opportunite = New SelectList(db.opportunite, "idOpportunite", "nomOffre")
            Return View()
        End If
  ...
```

---

I Still have a little problem, If I write :

```
 Function contactSearch(ByVal searchString As String, ByVal opportunite As Integer)
```

And if one of those fields is empty, I got this error : The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'opportunite'...

So, the only way I have to solve this was to use the code below. Isn't there any better way to solve this?

```
    Function contactSearch(ByVal search As String, ByVal opportunite As opportunite) As ViewResult
        Dim opport As Integer = 0
        Try
            opport = Val(Request("opportunite"))
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try

        If opport = 0 Then
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You incorrectly named your action arguments. Should be like this:

```
<HttpPost()>
Function contactSearch(ByVal searchString As String, ByVal opportunite As String) As ViewResult
    ...
```

Notice that the 2 arguments are of type String. In your code you have used some custom `opportunite` type for the second argument but this doesn't make sense because a DropDownList sends only the selected value. You cannot expect it to bind to a complex type.

Comment: the Html code of the selectlist gives smth like that : <option value="2">name</option>... Should I have written : "opportunite As Integer"? I also understand why it worked before, I asked the values inside the controller this way : Dim chaine As String = Request("searchString")

Comment: Yes, you could use Integer in this case. And yes that's why it worked before. Because you explicitly fetched the values from the Request object using the correct name. If you respect the same naming convention for your action argument parameters it will work as well so that you no longer need to manually fetch them from the Request object.

Comment: So, I edited my question, with another one, because I think that what I've done to solve my problem could be improved

Comment: The way to solve this is to make the `opportunite` parameter an Integer in your action method signature: `ByVal opportunite As Integer` and then directly use the value inside the controller action.

Comment: the problem is that if I do that, when I submit a form with opportunite that is empty, I receive the following error : The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'opportunite'...

Comment: In this case use a nullable integer: `Nullable(Of Integer)`.

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting the 'search' value?.

Try passing in the form collection to see what's getting posted

```
 public ActionResult CreateMarketingType(FormCollection form)
 {
      ...
 }
```